# Why does "from" email show a different list on single email versus bulk?

Tags: email

I checked the option that shows all my contact email address in the from list, and if I pull up a single contact and click Action -> Send Email, it will show the full list. But when I go to Mailings -> New Mailing, it only shows the list from the From Emails list screen. Can I send a bulk email using a from address from the logged in user's contact? That list is going to be a mile long if I have to add everyone that might send bulk email to the list. I toggled the yes/no a couple times and it definitely doesn't affect the new bulk mail screen. Is there some reason the new mailing screen is required to be limited this way? Could/should the one yes/no toggle control both, or could/should a second toggle be added to allow it?

On a side note, I noticed the Mailings -> New Mailing screen doesn't sort the dropdown in the same order indicated on the config screen. Actions -> New Email does sort the from list correctly, but New Mailing doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Sending an email using CiviMail is different from sending a one-off email to an individual contact, both technically and conceptually. Sending CiviMail is a much more fraught activity in terms of ip reputation, bounce handling, etc. since it is used to send thousand of emails or more. So it makes sense to have different rules, and one of those is to limit the different From: email addresses that allowed.

It sounds like you want everyone in your database to be able to send civimails from themselves? That doesn't sound like what CiviMail is intended for.

Perhaps you're looking for more of a mailing list functionality as provided by list serve type software (mailman, etc.)?

Comment: We have 20 or so people that need to send bulk email from their address. I would much prefer to clear out the static list and populate it with a few addresses like noreply@ and then configure each contact with their appropriate email addresses. For one thing, the way it is now, any user can send from any address in the list or from the main org, which is bad. Our users should only be able to send from noreply@ plus their own address. They should also be able to put their personal email in the reply-to field, which is similarly limited.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable set of requirements, and perhaps the beginning of a different question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What question? You mean a feature request?

Comment: You're describing a set of requirements of how you'd like to use CiviCRM, which is great. But it's not a specific question, and not exactly what you asked in the post above (which contains quite a few questions and observations). I'm suggesting you decide on what you really really want to ask and post that in a new post.